# How can I use the dark mode wallet in web3-onboard in React?

Tags: reactjs, web3-onboard

I'm using the web3-onboard package to enable wallet connection in my application. On the website of the package there is a [preview tool](https://onboard.blocknative.com/theming-tool) that uses a dark mode version of the wallet.

Does anybody know how I can enable this dark version? It seems like there are predefined styles such as light and dark, but I can't select them anywhere. There's a section in the docs that describes how to change individual css properties one by one, but no mention of actual themes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all *"unset"* with your styling options and paste in the `Onboard Config`:

```js
{
"--w3o-background-color": "unset", 
"--w3o-foreground-color": "unset", 
"--w3o-text-color": "unset", 
"--w3o-border-color": "unset", 
"--w3o-action-color": "unset", 
"--w3o-border-radius": "unset", 
}
```

Source: https://onboard.blocknative.com/theming-tool

You can also visit the theming tool and choose `Custom` option in the `Select Theme` dropdown and play with the values and copy the generated config.

Comment: I replaced the values but nothing happened, the popup is still white as before.

Comment: Also, where do you find this `Onboard Config`? I didn't see any mention of it in the docs. I pasted the values inside `::root`, but it made no difference.